# Best filesystem format for Samba between Linux and Windows

Tags: debian, windows, samba, file-sharing

I've made some researches but I don't find what I need. I have a Linux based server (under Debian 7.1) and several Windows computers. On my server I have some HD which I want to use as external hard drive.

My question is: What is the best filesystem format for this exchange NTFS or EXT on the exchange hard drive for best performances and security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by security you mean data integrity, then btrfs is the way to go. I am using it across multiple disks for months without any problem. You can extend it easily and change raid levels also easily (although not per subvolume, yet). Be sure to use the latest kernel and version for btrfs-tools. For more information go [here](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220015/how-to-use-btrfs-with-compression-on-external-usb-hard-drive) to name a few. If by security you mean data encryption, then [this](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Does_btrfs_support_encryption.3F) will be helpful for a start.